# Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). I can't seem to find the issue?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-proptypes

I'm trying to get my error handling to work by sending alerts to the user, I've singled out the problem to one component and where it's trying to render, I've scoured the documentation for any answers to why it's not working and have found nothing. Maybe I'm not seeing something right in front of me?

Here is my Alerts Component that's giving me the trouble.

```js
class Alerts extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    error: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    message: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { error, alert, message } = this.props;
    if (error !== prevProps.error) {
      if (error.msg.name) alert.error(`Name: ${error.msg.name.join()}`);
      if (error.msg.email) alert.error(`Email: ${error.msg.email.join()}`);
      if (error.msg.message)
        alert.error(`Message: ${error.msg.message.join()}`);
      if (error.msg.non_field_errors)
        alert.error(error.msg.non_field_errors.join());
      if (error.msg.username) alert.error(error.msg.username.join());
    }

    if (message !== prevProps.message) {
      if (message.deleteItem) alert.success(message.deleteItem);
      if (message.addItem) alert.success(message.addItem);
      if (message.passwordNotMatch) alert.error(message.passwordNotMatch);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Fragment />;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  error: state.errors,
  message: state.messages
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withAlert(Alerts));
```

And here's where I'm calling it:

```js
const alertOptions = {
  timeout: 3000,
  position: "top center"
};

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReduxProvider store={store}>
        <Provider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
          <Router>
            <Fragment>
              <Header />
              <Alerts />
              <div className="container">
                <Switch>
                  <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                  <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </Fragment>
          </Router>
        </Provider>
      </ReduxProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

And here's the Error I'm getting:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Comment: can you show withAlert?

Comment: Is there a place where you are creating an object of JSX to render? If there is, you should try creating an array of JSX instead. Paste withAlert here please.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the parenthesis for the withAlerts function call:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withAlert()(Alerts));
```

Answer (score 0):

We use

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withAlert(Alerts));
```

with older versions of alert modules so you cant try as shown below

```
import { withAlert } from "react-alert";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";


class Alerts extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    error: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    message: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { error, alert, message } = this.props;
    if (error !== prevProps.error) {
      if (error.msg.name) alert.error(`Name: ${error.msg.name.join()}`);
      if (error.msg.email) alert.error(`Email: ${error.msg.email.join()}`);
      if (error.msg.message)
        alert.error(`Message: ${error.msg.message.join()}`);
      if (error.msg.non_field_errors)
        alert.error(error.msg.non_field_errors.join());
      if (error.msg.username) alert.error(error.msg.username.join());
    }

    if (message !== prevProps.message) {
      if (message.deleteItem) alert.success(message.deleteItem);
      if (message.addItem) alert.success(message.addItem);
      if (message.passwordNotMatch) alert.error(message.passwordNotMatch);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <Fragment />;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  error: state.errors,
  message: state.messages
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withAlert()(Alerts));
```